# Broken pipe error in Django Nonrel when loading localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

Running Django Nonrel, with Google App Engine 2.6.0 and Python 2.7, I'm getting this exception when trying to load for the first time localhost and localhost/admin (I expect it will happen with any page, though):

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 57011)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
        self.process_request(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
        self.finish_request(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
        self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
      File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2438, in __init__
        BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
        self.finish()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
        self.wfile.flush()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
        self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
    error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Strangely enough, it only appears using Google Chrome. When using Firefox, it doesn't print any exception (or at least, I haven't been able to replicate this problem in Firefox after many tries).

Does anyone know something about this problem?.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been [a few](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-python/browse_thread/thread/619d46a1e3d08c67) [similar](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4716&q=chrome&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893353/why-is-dev-appserver-py-app-engine-dev-server-hanging-waiting-for-a-request) of race condition issues between Chrome and dev_appserver.py. The usual story is that Chrome opens multiple concurrent connections to the server, but sends a request on the second connection first. Because dev_appserver is single-threaded, the first request blocks, and the server hangs until someone gives up.

Supposedly starting Chrome with `--disable-preconnect` prevents this condition.

Comment: Oh, almost missed your answer. Thank you very much. Glad to know this is a known issue.